# Can't add item with existing Id to the database

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I have a comparsion list. I can add a product to it, but when I try to add another product to this list, I'm getting error:

*The instance of entity type 'ProductToCompare' cannot be tracked because another instance with the key value '{ProductComparsionId: 13}' is already being tracked*

What I am doing wrong?

[image]

**Models:**

```
public class ProductComparsion
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int? UserId { get; set; }
    public Guid SessionId { get; set; }
    public int CategoryId { get; set; }
    public DateTime Created { get; set; }
    public ICollection<ProductToCompare> ProductsToCompare { get; set; }
}

public class ProductToCompare
{
    public int ProductComparsionId { get; set; }
    public ProductComparsion ProductComparsion { get; set; }
    public int ProductId { get; set; }
    public Product Product { get; set; }        
}
```

**EF:**

```
public class AppDbContext : CmsDbContextBase, ILocalizedDbContext
{
    public DbSet<ProductComparsion> ProductsComparsion { get; set; }
    public DbSet<ProductToCompare> ProductsToCompare { get; set; }
}

public class AppDbContextModelProvider : ModelProvider
{
    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbContext dbContext, ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Entity<ProductComparsion>(typeBuiler =>
        {
            typeBuiler.ToTable(nameof(AppDbContext.ProductsComparsion));
            typeBuiler.HasKey(z => z.Id);
        });

        modelBuilder.Entity<ProductToCompare>(typeBuilder =>
        {
            typeBuilder.ToTable(nameof(AppDbContext.ProductsToCompare));
            typeBuilder.HasKey(z => z.ProductComparsionId);
            typeBuilder.HasOne(z => z.ProductComparsion).WithMany(z => z.ProductsToCompare).HasForeignKey(z => z.ProductComparsionId);
        });
    }
}
```

**Adding data to DB:**

```
    public async Task<ProductComparsionVM> AddProductToComparsionList(List<int> productIds, int listId = 0)
    {
        var comparsionList = await _dbContext.ProductsComparsion
            .AsNoTracking()
            .Include(z => z.ProductsToCompare)
            .FirstOrDefaultAsync(z => z.Id.Equals(listId));

        Guid sessionId = default;
        Guid.TryParse(_httpContextAccessor.HttpContext.Session.Id, out sessionId);

        var products = _dbContext.Products.Include(z => z.ProductCategories);

        foreach (var productId in productIds)
        {                
            comparsionList.ProductsToCompare.Add(new ProductToCompare { ProductId = productId });
            comparsionList.SessionId = sessionId;

            var user = _userManager.GetUserAsync(_httpContextAccessor.HttpContext.User).GetAwaiter().GetResult();
            comparsionList.UserId = user == null ? null : (int?)user.Id;
        }                          

        await _dbContext.AddAsync(comparsionList);
        await _dbContext.SaveChangesAsync();
        return null;
    }
```

**Edit 1**

[image]

[image]

Comment: Can you please focus on specific area where you have error?

Comment: @T.S. When I save added item to the database on line await `_dbContext.AddAsync(comparsionList);`, I'm getting error. I in posman for field `ListId` I enter `Id` which is not existed in the DB, the it works fine. But one list should contain more than one product and I need to be able to add products to the same list

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The key on the `ProductToCompare` model is configured as `ProductComparisonId`, and there is also a relationship configured between the `ProductToCompare` and the `ProductComparison` models on that property.

So when you add a `ProductToCompare` instance to `ProductComparison.ProductsToCompare`, the `ProductToCompare` instance is getting the `ProductComparison` instance's `ProductComparisonId`. Once you add more than one `ProdcutToCompare` to a `ProductComparison` you have two instances of `ProductToCompare` with the same `ProductComparisonId`... the same key. This is why you're getting the error.

Add an `Id` to `ProductToCompare` and make that the key, or maybe make the key composite between `ProductId` and `ProductComparisonId` to fix it.

Comment: Thank you. I added `Id` but now can't update database with new migration. Don't you know, why is this happening?

Comment: I'm afraid not. I'm fortunate in that I've never had to change the key in a migration in this fashion. Sorry :(.